# flutter 2.2 update code stopped working and no emulator in some projects

Tags: flutter, dart, updates, nullable, dart-null-safety

I formatted my laptop lately and all projects stopped,
in the main method the first class, I have these errors

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  static void setLocale(BuildContext context, Locale locale) {
    _MyAppState state = context.findAncestorStateOfType<_MyAppState>();
    state.setLocale(locale);
  }

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Locale _locale;
```

error 1 say error: A value of type '_MyAppState?' can't be assigned to a variable of type '_MyAppState'. (invalid_assignment at [AppName] lib\main.dart:35)
error 2 say error: Non-nullable instance field '_locale' must be initialized. (not_initialized_non_nullable_instance_field at [AppName] lib\main.dart:44)

I can't use null anymore

```
  setState(() {
        if (stut != null) buttonState = 0;
      });
```

there is error on stut error: The non-nullable local variable 'stut' must be assigned before it can be used. (not_assigned_potentially_non_nullable_local_variable at [AppName] lib\myWidgets\AddToBasketButton.dart:65),

required and unrequired problem
here is my code

```
class SectionButtonClass {
  final String title, image;
  final int index;
  final String phone;
  // final Color titleColor;
  const SectionButtonClass(
      {required this.title, required this.image, this.index, this.phone});
}
```

there is an error with all unrequired variables, for note, it was @required after the update I had to delete the @ signal.

pressBack method with WillPopScop stopped working with errors

```
  // ignore: missing_return
  Future<bool> _pressBack() {
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) {
          return widget.backTo;
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

error: The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type. (body_might_complete_normally at [AppName] lib\UI\AboutUsScr.dart:43)

```
  // ignore: missing_return
  Future<bool> pressBack() {
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
        new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => LoginScr()));
  }
```

error: The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type. (body_might_complete_normally at [AppName] lib\UI\ActivePhoneNoForgetMyPasswordCodeScr.dart:132)

Comment: Can you run `flutter doctor` and paste your `pubspec.yaml`? 
You probably have new version of Dart now which is expecting you to use null safety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open your `pubspec.yaml` file, probably you have something like this:

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  // sdk might be also set to 2.12.0
  sdk: ">=2.9.0 <3.0.0" 
//rest
```

Anyway, the problem with this and your code is that starting from `Dart v2.9` there is a feature called `null-safety`: [Read more here](https://codewithandrea.com/videos/dart-null-safety-ultimate-guide-non-nullable-types/#:%7E:text=Dart%202.9%20introduces%20Sound%20Null,we%27re%20doing%20something%20wrong)

In order to go around this, you can downgrade your `sdk` to version lower than `2.9.0` for example like `2.7.0`, which is maybe easier option, but not better.

In order to really work with the latest standards, you need to start implementing null safety in your code in a way that e.g. `Key key` will now be `Key? key`.

More information also here: https://dart.dev/null-safety

Comment: so you mean that i need to change it to 2.7.0?

Comment: That is one option, yes! But it might happen that you'll have to downgrade your Flutter version.

Comment: This should be in your `pubspec. yaml` file: `sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0" `

Comment: Try `flutter clean`

Comment: dont work, emulator still open in some project not all